# How to create popup window(modal dialog box) in HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

On my web site a have a page where  where user can ask questions.
Now I want to add Add Image button that must invoke kinda modal dialog box where user
needs to upload the picture from computer. Then window is closed and  link to image is placed back to post.

I wanna do something similar like in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask - try pressing Image button and u'll see nice popup window coming up.

Please suggest what is best way to implement that stuff. I am asking for code snippet rather about technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need client side scripting.  I reccomend learning Javascript, then Jquery, then Jquery UI.  If you know php it should not be too dificult to pickup the basics.

Comment: Hi Matt, yeah I am looking at Jquery UI they have a dialog box, can you please explain how to upload using jscript because I cannot use form based file uploading then

Comment: @Captain Comic If you are sure you need a javascript upload instead of the much simpler form submit upload, I use this http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: @Captain Comic ajax is your friend. Its what allows every web app and fancy, responsive webpage.  Ajax really should get its own national holiday.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this could be of some help once you have started http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form. Other wise you can use the DOM structure and create each and every element using appendChild and CreateElement and use css to give a good look.

Answer (score 1):

That popup window you can do by using any jQuery Library like colorbox. For image upload thing you will have to alternately look for some Flash Based or Java based uploads.

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html
http://swfupload.org/

Answer (score 1):

easy as drink water ;)

with jquery create pop up ... like this ( http://fancybox.net/ ) and then add form to pop up for upload image ... then when file uploaded only return absolute address to parent editor ... now you can show your image ;)