# error message using modals for login

Tags: php, authentication

i need to show a dialog box if login failed. now i'm able to show the error line inside the form, but i need to show the error message using `modals`.
here's my code:

```
$sfAuth = new SfAuthenticate();
$sfHelper = new SfHelper();

$user = $_POST['txtUsername'];
$pass = $_POST['txtPassword'];  

$checkUser = $sfAuth->checkUserJobSeeker($user);

if($checkUser)
{
    $login = $sfAuth->loginJobSeeker($user, $pass);
    if($login)
    {           
        echo $sfHelper->redirect('forms/jobSeeker/HomeJobSeeker.php');
    }else{

        echo $sfHelper->redirect('forms/jobSeeker/formLoginJobSeeker.php?err=Invalid Username or Password');
    }
}else{
    echo $sfHelper->redirect('forms/jobSeeker/formLoginJobSeeker.php?err=Sorry, We Cannot found your Username');
    }
```

i want to show the dialog box after redirecting to the login form.
can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

To show a modal dialog box you'll need javascript. Check this previous SO question: [How to create popup window(modal dialog box) in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337417/1349295)). I would, similarly, recommend checking out [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) which is an extension of the javascript library jQuery.

In 3 steps, here's how this works:

**Include jQuery and jQueryUI library scripts in the page**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"/></script>
```

**Create the markup for the modal dialog to be displayed**

Doesn't need to be fancy but note the `id` tag as jQuery uses that to know which element to display in dialog.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the message inside the modal dialog.</p>
</div>
```

**Show the dialog using jQueryUI**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
</script>
```

See a full working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wjp94/3/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this fiddle, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/7PwWp/5/

As to launching the modal window on user error, you can add a condition:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['err']): ?>
  launchWindow('#message');
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the message box, you can put:

```
<p><?php echo (isset($_GET['err'])? $_GET['err']:''; ?></p>
```

Comment: I suspect some extra code would be required to close the modal box afterward to return back to the main view?

Comment: ah yes.. updated now to include close statement. just click on 'close' or outside of the modal to close it

Answer (score 0):

put this code on formLoginJobSeeker.php file

```
<?php
if($_GET['err'] == "Sorry, We Cannot found your Username")\
{
echo '<script> alert("Sorry Wrong Username Or Password");</script>'
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show dialog then you have to use jquery dialog

Add following code to your page;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"/></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none">
  <p>
         <?php if(isset($_GET['err'])) echo $_GET['err'];?>
  </p>
</div>


<?php if(isset($_GET['err']){ ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

         $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

if you want to see how your modal looks like check on this link 
http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8p

Answer (score 0):

Solved?
If not, here is my solution.

Redirect to sth like that (notice `#run_modal`):

```
`forms/jobSeeker/formLoginJobSeeker.php?err=YOUR_MESSAGE#run_modal`
```

and JS:

```
function detectModalParam()
{
    var hash = $(location).attr('hash');

    if (hash == '#run_modal')
    {
        YOUT_MODAL_FUNCTION();
    };
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    detectModalParam();
}
```